# CSS/HTML: Alignment issue in IE9 + jsFiddle

Tags: html, css, slider, alignment, space

I have an odd alignment issue where an extra space is being added. Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/aVdGE/1/

I'm using IE9 with both my project and jsFiddle. Here is a picture of the jsFiddle result and here is the result viewed not in jsFiddle (left = jsFiddle, right = IE). The code is identical:

[image]

Comment: Your fiddle looks the same to me in IE9, Chrome, and FF.

Comment: I don't have IE here, but could it be IE ads more spacing to the ul element? What does the inspector say? And what is the result if you give all elements a border?

Comment: If I uncheck "Normalized CSS" in your fiddle, FF and IE show the gap but Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `padding:0` to `#slider ul`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE9 running here at the moment, but I did spot this `line-height: 1.35;` .... 1.35 what? No indication of measurement may be causing an unintended size.